# C++ : const declrations duplicate symbols issue

Tags: c++

I want to avoid #defines in my code. Accordingly, I have the following in a header file :

```
 #ifndef __GATENAMES__
 #define __GATENAMES__

  namespace GateNames
  {
  const char*   CBSD_GATE_TO_SAS            = "CbsdGate_SAS_INOUT";
  const char*   CBSD_GATE_TO_SAS_OUT        = "CbsdGate_SAS_INOUT$o";
  const char*   CBSD_GATE_TO_SAS_IN         = "CbsdGate_SAS_INOUT$i";
  const char*   SAS_GATE_TO_CBSD            = "SasGate_CBSD_INOUT";
  const char*   SAS_GATE_TO_ESC         = "SasGate_ESC_INOUT";
  const char*  SAS_GATE_TO_ESC_OUT         = "SasGate_ESC_INOUT$o";
  const char*  SAS_GATE_TO_ESC_IN         = "SasGate_ESC_INOUT$i";
};
#endif
```

This header file is included in various places in my code. However, the linker complains that the symbols are multiply defined:

```
../out/gcc-debug/src/CbsdSim.o:(.data.rel.local+0x0): multiple definition of `GateNames::CBSD_GATE_TO_SAS'
```

How can I get around this problem? Thanks.

Comment: A basic rule in C++ is to declare in headers but define in only one compile unit. Put the definitions in a cpp file and change the headers to only declare the const chars*.

Comment: @doug No, that's not a basic rule of C++ - it is a rule in C.

Comment: @doug: That rule taken literally would mean that you could not define classes in header files, only forward-declare them.

Comment: By the way, you should not use `ALL_UPPERCASE` for anything but macros. Using `ALL_UPPERCASE` for constants is either a C-ism or a Java-ism, but it has no place in C++.

Comment: @Neil and Christian. true, I should have said instantiate objects in only one compiling unit, and there are exceptions to that for templates and definitions defined within a class declaration. The general rule does apply to the OP's usage.

Comment: @doug No, it doesn't. Using things like `const int MEANING = 42` in header files is very common C++ practice, and was in fact invented by Stroustrup to do away with #define macros. The OP is simply extending this practice to pointers, which is  also very common in C++ programs.

Comment: @Neil, of course, as your answer shows. In such a case the scope is limited to the compilation unit. Much as a static definition is local. The OP's definitions were global.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firstly, names like this `__GATENAMES__`, (any name starting with an underscore and an uppercase letter or containing two consecutive underscores) is reserved for the C++ implementation - you shgould not be creating such names in your own code.

Secondly, your constness is a bit mixed up, instead of things like:

```
const char*   CBSD_GATE_TO_SAS            = "CbsdGate_SAS_INOUT";
```

you want:

```
 const char *  const CBSD_GATE_TO_SAS            = "CbsdGate_SAS_INOUT";
```

In other words, it's the pointer that's got to be const to limit the linkage of the pointer, not the thing pointed to (although in this case that also has to be const).

Comment: What about `auto const CBSD_GATE_TO_SAS  = "CbsdGate_SAS_INOUT";`?

Comment: @Christian Depends how wedded to auto you are, I guess.

Comment: I like the const char* const ... way of doing things better. It is clear what is going on. Thanks for the answers.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for your linker errors is that non const variables have external linkage, and since you defined them in multiple translation units (by including a header), linker complains.

There are three ways to fix your code. First is to change linkage of your `const char*` string literals, by making them static. This way they have internal linkage, and each translation unit which includes them will not share them with other translation units - so also linker will not complain:

```
static const char*   CBSD_GATE_TO_SAS            = "CbsdGate_SAS_INOUT";
^^^^^^
```

Second one is to make them const:

```
const char* const  CBSD_GATE_TO_SAS            = "CbsdGate_SAS_INOUT";
            ^^^^^
```

which is actually quite similar to making them static, they have now internal linkage.

Third way is to declare them in header file and define in one single translation unit.:

```
// in header file
namespace GateNames
{
extern const char* CBSD_GATE_TO_SAS         ;
};
```

in some .cpp file:

```
namespace GateNames
{
const char*   CBSD_GATE_TO_SAS            = "CbsdGate_SAS_INOUT";
};
```

Comment: If you want these things to be compile-time constants, which you probably do, then only the second of the above is an option.

Comment: @NeilButterworth why not third solution? This at least makes sure that no duplicated string literals will exists. I know linkers might merge them, but I dont think it is guaranteed.

Comment: At compile time, when compiling a file that includes the header, the compiler can only see `extern const char* CBSD_GATE_TO_SAS;`, but to use it at compile time it needs to see the actual string literal that the variable points to, and in fact the variable needs to be a constant.

Comment: But what is it good for at compile time? Compiler will any way store address of literal to use it at runtime, ie. with strcmp or strcat. Maybe OP is going to use it in some advanced constexpr classes which will do some compile time computations with those strings - but it was not in the question.

Comment: "Compiler will any way store address of literal to use it at runtime" - no it won't. The address won't be known until link time.